# What is the value of xyz?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b$ and $c$ are not equal to $0$ and $1$ and if $a^x=b,b^y=c,c^z=a$,then $xyz=?$
We have tried to solve by equation,but it can't produce the desired result.

Comment: Perhaps you sould assume that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive. Otherwise you must deal with powers like $(-1)^{\pi}$.

Comment: Indeed, if we are not told that $a,b,c$ are positive and real, we can have $xyz$ equalling all sorts of things.  One can prove by the monotonicity of $e^x$ that for $a>0, a\neq 1$ one has $a^v=a^w$ if and only if $v=w$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a=c^z=(b^y)^z=b^{yz}=(a^x)^{yz}=a^{xyz}$$
$$xyz=1$$

Comment: Maybe you should write $a = c^z = \ldots = a^{xyz}$ instead. This would use the assumptions at the correct steps.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: examine $((a^x)^y)^z$ in different ways.